# "doubleton" or how to have two global instances of a module

Tags: node.js

I am playing with node.js porting a webAPI currently implemented in Delphi and learning how to do things the node way.

My application uses two instances of a database-backend connected to a different DB each. Service-code can get a connection to each from one of two global instances of a connection-pool.

How would one do this in node.js?

I know how to write the pool as a module exporting a constructor so I can create two instances, configured with a different connection string. I can hold these in global variables in the main server-file or in a module holding references to various services and doing routing of requests.

But how would the individual service-modules that want to get a connection, do something with it and then return it to the pool get access?

So far I have been happy with require()-ing such shared modules everywhere I use them, so they behave as singletons and the state is shared between everywhere they are require()-ed. But how to do that if I want two (or n) instances that are configured differently?

All I can think of so far is actively injecting a reference to them everywhere. Would work, but is that the proper solution?

P.S.: I did not know up to now that Doubletons are a thing.

Comment: `require`-ing should only give back the class function that you have to instantiate in order to use, not an instance. So, just `require` once and instantiate twice? As for how to access them globally, just keep a reference to them in your global namespace? Or create an auxiliary class that creates those two instance and acts as a singleton?

Comment: Thank you, a very useful answer.

Yes, an extra module that holds the instances seems to be the way to go.

I also tried putting two instances of my Pool class into the global namespace. This did not work right away because I misunderstood nodes mechanism of encapsulating modules. Using 

global.poolA

instead of just

var poolA

fixed that.

I have a better understanding now and am happy with the result.